# Drawn Bitmaps Disappearing After Invoking Function to Alter Vector

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe

I am trying to randomize the positions of MovieClips in a Vector. to be added to the main stage's display list. I have this function that generates the MovieClips with their properties:

```
    private function initMovieClips():Vector.<MovieClip>                                                                                                                                                                                
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        var initVec:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>();                                                                                                                                                                      

        for (var i:int = 0; i < Math.ceil(this.numBlocks / 2); i++)                                                                                                                                                                     
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

            var typeVarianceChance:Number = Math.random();                                                                                                                                                                              
            var colorVarianceChance:Number = Math.random();                                                                                                                                                                             

            var ranType:Number = Math.floor(this.numTypes * Math.random());                                                                                                                                                             

            var coRanType:Number;                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            if (typeVarianceChance < .2)                                                                                                                                                                                                
            {                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                coRanType = Math.floor(this.numTypes * Math.random());                                                                                                                                                                  
            } else {                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                coRanType = this.typeHash[ranType];                                                                                                                                                                                     
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

            var ranColor:Number = Math.floor(this.imageURLs.length * Math.random());                                                                                                                                                    

            var coRanColor:Number;                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            if (colorVarianceChance > .1)                                                                                                                                                                                               
            {                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                coRanColor = Math.floor(this.imageURLs.length * Math.random());                                                                                                                                                         
            } else {                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                coRanColor = ranColor;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

            var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();                                                                                                                                                                                         
            var comc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();                                                                                                                                                                                       

            mc.type = ranType;                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            comc.type = coRanType;                                                                                                                                                                                                      

            mc.color = ranColor;                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            comc.color = coRanColor;                                                                                                                                                                                                    

            initVec.push(mc,comc);                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        return initVec;                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    }
```

Bitmaps are then loaded and drawn onto each of the images. I then invoke this function to randomly "shuffle" the Vector.

```
    private function shuffle(vec:Vector.<MovieClip>):Vector.<MovieClip>                                                                                                                                                                 
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        var shuffled:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>();                                                                                                                                                                     
        var origLength:uint = vec.length;                                                                                                                                                                                               

        for (var i:int = 0; i < origLength; i++){                                                                                                                                                                                       
            var ranPos:uint = Math.floor(Math.random() * vec.length);                                                                                                                                                                   
            shuffled.push(vec[ranPos]);                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            delete vec[ranPos];                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        return shuffled;                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    }
```

If I don't invoke the shuffle function the Bitmaps are drawn just fine. But if I invoke the shuffle function on my Vector. to be drawn onto the screen some of the MovieClips are not displaying after I add them to the display list (which I've tested and know is happening). Some randomly appear and some don't. Which ones display and which ones don't appears to be random each time I run my application (maybe it has something to do with my `initMovieClips` function, which uses pseudorandom code?).

I've tried implementing the shuffle function at different points in my code, in places where the Bitmaps have already been drawn, and in places where I haven't even invoke the function to start loading the Bitmaps (so I don't think it's a threading issue). I even tried inserting code to draw a simple test circle on every MovieClip's graphics property. Just to see if it was a problem with the Bitmaps, but the one's that weren't being drawn showed no Bitmap or test circle. This leads me to believe that it's a problem with the graphics property itself. Which leaves me completely stumped. Any ideas on what it could be?

Comment: Wouldn't be a threading issue anyway because flash runs on a single thread.

Comment: I think everything runs on one thread with the exception of network related stuff (loading, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I think the probably is in the for loop. You are looping through the length for your vec (which in this case I'm going to assume is initVec). But in order to get the index of vec you do a randomize

```
var ranPos:uint = Math.floor(Math.random() * vec.length); 
shuffled.push(vec[ranPos]);
```

so now whats happening is that although you may getting values from 0 to length of vec, you may be repeating the same value twice. So if vec.length = 5 you may get 1, 2, 3,2,4 in which case you are missing 5 and getting 2 twice, this order is basically "random" so in a large scale you may not be going though all your vec[] values

another way of doing this would be to use a while loop and if random brings an index thats already been used retry until all index values have been used (brute force), if you're vec.length is massive try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Shuffling_algorithms

Comment: If delete was keeping the value of the vector set to null, instead of adjusting the size of the vector overall, then this would be the case. I'll look into it.